# How to force users to register with e-mail in ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to force users to register with their e-mail addresses DataType.EmailAddress doesn't work.

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "E-mail")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your wanting validation for an email address, you need the `[EmailAddress]` attribute (NET 4.5)

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "E-mail")]
[EmailAddress] // Add this
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

or for NET 4.0 you can use a `[RegularExpression]` attribute (this one is taken from jquery-validate 1.9.0)

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "E-mail")]
[RegularExpression(@"^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))$", ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid email adress")]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Note the `[DataType]` attributes are used by `@Html.EditorFor()` to render the `type` attribute used by browsers (e.g `type="email"`)

Comment: I believe that EmailAddressAttribute was added in .net 4.5, and the question is about MVC4 which I would assume would be .net 4.0

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch. What? I'm using MVC 4 and it works for me.

Comment: Do you have .net 4.5 installed?

Comment: Yes I do, but your down voting on the assumption that OP has VS 2010 and not updated

Comment: That's the most likely scenario.  The only reason to use MVC4 is if you are on .net 4, as MVC5 requires .net 4.5

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch, When I installed VC 2012, In came with MVC 4 and NET 4.5

Comment: Regardless, I downvoted because you make no mention of it being a .net 4.5 only feature, and it will confuse users who are on .net 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "EmailAddress" annotation:

```
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

EDIT:

For MVC 4 and below, you can use regex expression to do validation on Email address fields.
See more here:

http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-email-address-with-regular-expression/

Comment: Also you would want to add some validations at the database side if necessary.

Comment: EmailAddressAttribute requires .net 4.5, mvc4 typically uses .net 4.0